# How to compare different programming languages?

Tags: language-agnostic

Sorry, but I couldn't find any relevant questions on Stack Overflow. However, I found this info graphic.
https://www.udemy.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/PROGRAMMING-LANGUAGE-3.png
So. I often hear that some languages are said to have higher perfomance or to be more productive. For example, in introduction to The Pragmatic Programmer's Guide Yukihiro Matsumoto calls his language "more powerful than Perl, and more object-oriented than Python". While it is obvious that representatives of different paradigms have their own pros and cons (C generally has higher perfomance while Python makes the process of development more simple), it's still unclear what are the criteria in comparison within the same paradigm and how the ties are broken.

Comment: The ugly truth is that comparing language (in general/as a whole -- i.e. except for a very narrow purpose and specific circumstances) is not possible and we're all just stupid kids who like to throw dirt at each other.

Comment: This question would be a better fit for programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: @delnan , suddenly, this looks like a legit answer. The community of its users and personal experience seems to be as important as the advantages of particular tool set.

Comment: @delnan, wrong, it is perfectly possible to compare the languages (as well as any other tools) in a controlled experiment.

Comment: @SK-logic Of course. That's exactly what I was referring to: *for a very narrow purpose and specific circumstances*. It's just not what most people mean when they "compare" languages, and of course the results are only applicable to that specific case, so it's a bit of an exotic concern.

Comment: @delnan, ok, *for any given narrow purpose and specific circumstances* *any two given languages* can be objectively compared in a controlled experiment. This is what the word "comparison" means, and I'm not aware of any other *valid* meanings. But, yes, since most of the self-proclaimed "programmers" are not scientists, they may understand it differently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the Computer Language Benchmarks Game (aka Programming Language Shootout):

https://benchmarksgame-team.pages.debian.net/benchmarksgame/performance/mandelbrot.html

Comment: (Just don't say *aka* anything or the benchmarks game admin will have a hissy fit, about a name change that happened over 5 years ago.)

Comment: Oh, thanks for the note, I did not know that. But: I was googling for programming language shootout, as this was the name which was stuck in my brain. Note that language and especially proper names are choosen by people who *use* the name, not by people owning the property.

Comment: Google "fastest programming language", and you'll find the website and that isn't the name. Google "speed jruby", and you'll find the website and that isn't the name. Google "reverse complement", and you'll find the website, and that isn't the name.